# Special characters in search

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

I have created a sample product named `hashtag ### example`

I can find this product when searching it with hashtag, hash, example, ... but not with ###

the url looks like this: `/catalogsearch/result/?q=%23%23%23`

how can I make this work?

### EDIT 1: [image: my search settings]

### EDIT 2:

I also tried searching a product with the name %23%23%23 by putting ### in the search bar. but with no results. I also can't find that product when searching for %23%23%23

Comment: Can you try with four # (####)?

Comment: @KAndy not working.... why should it?

Comment: @PhilippSander, got the solution for this?